# How to download files from project asset folder as zip in angular

Tags: angular, image, video, download, zip

I have an Angular project where I have images and videos that are stored in the assets folder and I want to download all of them as a .zip file on a button click. Is this possible?

Comment: How do those files get there? If they are in the assets folder, that probably means they are already there during compile time.. and if so, why not simply pre-zip them..?

Comment: Those are the sample files used to display in application and when user clicks on 'download all' those should be downloaded as zip.

Comment: https://www.thecodehubs.com/download-files-in-zip-format-in-angular-9/

The above reference link helps user to upload files and then download those as zip. Instead of uploading and downloading, is it possible to directly download from project asset folder path?

Comment: https://github.com/Stuk/jszip - this library will handle all of the heavy lifting for you and exposes a simple API